# How to remove the space created above the keyboard in Flutter ؟

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

How to remove the white space created on the top of the keyboard? I did everything I could think of, but I didn't get any results

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = ScreenSizeService(context).width;
    final screenHeight = ScreenSizeService(context).height;
    var selected;
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        child: TextField(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you want this white space to be filled up with? keyboard? because you have only a textfield, it takes few pixels of height. Rest is white.

Comment: I want this white space to disappear

Comment: and fill it with what?

Comment: the white space will not be there if you would be using smaller size device.  I have not understand what design you are thinking of.

Comment: A list is displayed at the bottom of the text field. But when the keyboard is opened, this white space above the keyboard does not display the list completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Keyboard'),
      ),
      body: _MyPage(),
    ),
  ));
}

class _MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(),
        Flexible(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (_, index) =>
                ListTile(title: Text(index.toRadixString(16))),
            itemCount: 40,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Does it solve your issue?

[image]

Comment: pls see image HOW TO REMOVE SPACE BETWEEN KEYBOARD

Comment: tnx remove padding how to add appbar ???

Comment: I have already added appbar in above code

Answer (score 0):

The reason for lot of wasted space was because **there was a Scaffold inside a Scaffold**. Each scaffold adding space for keyboard. Removing one solved the problem.

answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49584482/14409491